# Splitting lines from an input file

Tags: arrays, perl, join, input, split

If you have an input like

```
5 28
108 2 3
```

how would you get it to print out

```
A = {5, 28}
B = {108, 2, 3}
```

I don't understand how to split it correctly in the right spots with the different line inputs.
I know I'm supposed to have something like this in the code.

```
@A = split (" ", $line1)
@B = split (" ", $line2)
```

Comment: Specifying the string `" "` as the first argument to `split` splits on any whitespace, so it should work. What problem do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex:

```
 @A = split (/ /, $line1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this perhaps?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $letter = 'A';

while ( <DATA> ) {
  printf "%s = {%s}\n", $letter++, join ', ', split;
}

__DATA__
5 28
108 2 3
```

**output**

```
A = {5, 28}
B = {108, 2, 3}
```